# Значение слов в тексте документа

Tags: значение-слов

В каком значении употребляются слова в тексте документа:

*акт, акция, закон, законный, квартиронаниматель, представление, судоговорение*?

Comment: Вы забыли сам документ процитировать. И, пожалуйста, научитесь пользоваться кнопкой **Shift**.

Comment: И вообще, для этого есть словари, в том числе в Интернете, обратитесь к ним

Comment: Спасибо за советы,никаких документов в задании нет,а в словарях,увы,я не смогла найти ответ на вопрос,значение по толковому словарю это одно,а в каком значении употребляется слово в тексте документа мне непонятно